# SQL combined and select older by one day

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a string query that does this select the title, description columns from event_planner table where the month,day,year is not older than today.

My table structure is setup like this.

Title, Description, Month, Day, Year

Format example of month is 05, day is 31, year is 2014. Have to do it in this format for a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an mysql installation nearby, so it may not work. Please feel free to try:

```
select title, description from event_planner
 where 
date(CONCAT('year','-',LPAD('month',2,'00'),'-',LPAD('day',2,'00'))) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: SELECT title,description FROM event_planner WHERE CONCAT(Year,'-',Month,'-',Day) >= CURDATE() 

This worked.

Answer (score 2):

As a note, converting the columns to a date time format is unnecessary.  It is cheaper to do the conversion on the "constant" side, the current date:

If they are stored as strings, then try:

```
where concat(year, month, day) >= date_format(curdate(), '%y%m%d')
```

If they are stored as numbers:

```
where year*10000 + month*100 + day >= year(now())*10000 + month(now()) * 100 + day(now())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store date as DATE type (e.g. in "date" column instad of last three columns you have). This way, you can use:

```
SELECT title, description FROM event_planner WHERE date >= CURDATE()
```

You can always extract day, month and year in your application logic when you retrieve the date value if it's needed for anything else.

Comment: I agree that this would be better, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does, you have to alter the table the way it should be done and use provided query.

Comment: I have to structure it like that by month, day, and year. I'm looking for way to do where date >= CURDATE() example but it combines the month, day, and year into one query.

Comment: You can use DAY(), MONTH() and YEAR() SQL functions for extraction if that data is needed elsewhere. I don't see the point of storing the data under non-standard data type, it will (eventually) become too hard to maintain

Answer (score 1):

SELECT title,description FROM event_planner WHERE CONCAT(Year,'-',Month,'-',Day) >= CURDATE()

This worked for me! Thanks guys!!